# How to send trap messages from linux to snmp agent on my local machine?

Tags: node.js, linux, net-snmp

I could not find any solution on internet so i decided to post my question on stackoverflow, I have a program on linux server when i execute it should send trap messages to my local snmp agent. I am setting host name to my system IP address, so i see all logs are printing from the program but its not sedning traps to my local snmp agent any idea how i can make it work in this case ?

app.js

```
var snmp = require("net-snmp");
var msg = require('./event.js');

function process (msg) {
    var host = msg.event.body.trapHost;
    var snmpVersion = snmp.Version1;
    if (msg.event.body.snmpVersion === "v2"){
        snmpVersion = snmp.Version2c
    }
    var sessionOptions = {
        port: 161,
        retries: 1,
        timeout: 5000,
        transport: "udp4",
        trapPort: msg.event.body.trapPort,
        version: snmpVersion
    };
    //Create snmp Session
    var session = snmp.createSession(host,"public",sessionOptions);
    var trapOid = msg.event.body.snmp.trapOID;
    var varbinds = msg.event.body.snmp.appOIDs;
    var options = {upTime: 1000};
    varbinds.forEach(function (oids) {
        oids.type = snmp.ObjectType.OctetString;
        console.log(oids.value);
    });
    try {
        if (snmp.isVarbindError(varbinds)) {
            Logger.error(snmp.varbindError(varbinds));
         } else {
            session.trap(trapOid, varbinds, options, function (error) {
                if (error)
                    console.log(error);
                else
                console.log('SNMP successfully delivered');
            });

        }
    } catch (e) {
        console.log("SNMP processing error: " + e);
    }
};

process(msg);
```

event.js

```
module.exports = {
        event: {
            header: {
                eventSource: "d-snmp"
            },
            body: {
                snmp: {
                    trapHost:"135.68.100.236",
                    trapPort:"162",
                    trapOID:"1.3.6.1.4.140.625",
                    appOIDs:  [
                        {
                            oid: "1.3.6.1.4.140.900",
                            type: "",
                            value: "Problem with Hardware"
                        },
                        {
                            oid: "1.3.6.1.4.140.700",
                            type: "",
                            value: "Hardware ok"
                        }
                     ]
                },
                snmpVersion: "v2"
            }
        }

};
```

Comment: If this is really important to you, and you haven't received any meaningful help after 24 hrs, you may want to consider offering a bounty for a solution. (I can't help in any case), but once your Q falls off of the first 1-2 pages, the likelyhood of getting help is reduced significantly. Good luck!